# Can rank(AB) < rank(A) and rank(AB) < rank(B) hold for matrices A and B?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I think that the statement is true because every row in AB is a linear combination of B and every column in AB is a linear combination of A. Therefore C(AB) ⊆ C(A) and R(AB) ⊆ R(B) so rank(AB) must be <= min(rank(A), rank(B))
Although I'm not sure whether my proof is enough and right. How else would you prove it?

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: 1. Do you mean $<$ or $\leq$? (You state one but prove the other.) 2. Have you tried to write down $2 \times 2$ examples based on your theoretical considerations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh yes! Just take any non-zero matrix $A$ such that $A^2=0$, for instance
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$